Nextjs 14 ImageResponse sometimes returning CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
All of a sudden I'm getting this error when trying to return an ImageResponse. It does not happen every time. For what its worth, I have a self hosted next app, meaning I'm not using vercel for hosting.
Method to import image
const logo = await fetchAsset(new URL("./assets/logo.png", import.meta.url));

helper function (based on how Next shows to load fonts)
export async function fetchAsset(url: URL): Promise<string> {
  const buffer = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
  const base64 = Buffer.from(buffer).toString("base64");
  return `data: image / png; base64, ${base64}`;
}

Error: failed to pipe response
      at pipeToNodeResponse (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/pipe-readable.js:111:15)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async NextNodeServer.runEdgeFunction (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1221:13)
      at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:242:37)
      at async NextNodeServer.handleRequestImpl (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:805:17) {
    [cause]: Error: fetch failed
        at context.fetch (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/sandbox/context.js:272:38)
        at a (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:13:43784)
        at B (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:13:71465)
        at /app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:13:73583
        at /app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:13:78344
        at i.with (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:8:19930)
        at u.with (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:8:14130)
        at u.startActiveSpan (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:8:29182)
        at i.startActiveSpan (/app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:8:29716)
        at /app/.next/server/app/[project_id]/route.js:13:78196 {
      cause: Error: certificate has expired
          at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1659:34)
          at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
          at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1070:8)
          at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:856:12)
          at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
        code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED'
      }
    }
  }

Alternative image import method with more context
import logo from "./assets/logo.png";
import background from "./assets/background.png";

const generateImage = async (
  query: Schema,
  project: ProjectConfig
): Promise<ImageResponse> => {
  const config = await getConfig();
  const { weights: fontWeights, options: fontOptions } = config.font;

  const product = await getProduct("0072745804588");

  return new ImageResponse(
    (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            position: "absolute",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <img
            src={background.src}
            width="1200"
            height="630"
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", objectFit: "cover" }}
          />
        </div>
        <div tw="flex flex-col h-full items-center justify-center">
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              fontFamily: "Inter-Bold",
              color: "black",
              fontSize: 54,
            }}
          >
            {product.name}
          </div>

          <img style={{ borderRadius: 10 }} src={logo.src} width={84} />
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
    {
      width: 1200,
      height: 630,
      fonts: fontOptions,
      headers: project.headers,
    }
  );
};

Result
Error: failed to pipe response
    at pipeToNodeResponse (/Users/garymiller/Development/Obsurv/unfurl-api/node_modules/next/dist/server/pipe-readable.js:111:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DevServer.runEdgeFunction (/Users/garymiller/Development/Obsurv/unfurl-api/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1221:13)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/garymiller/Development/Obsurv/unfurl-api/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:242:37)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/garymiller/Development/Obsurv/unfurl-api/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:805:17) {
  [cause]: Error: Image source must be an absolute URL: /_next/static/media/background.97147ca4.png
      at yt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:19061:177)
      at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:19301:53)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at cu (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:19301:44)
      at xl (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:23559:23)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async render (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:25420:17)
      at async Object.start (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.edge.js:25456:33)

If I try using a Next Image tag like <Image src={logo} width={84} /> I get a similar error with TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string. If I try <Image src={logo.src} width={84} /> I get a similar error like TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
It seems like using images in an edge runtime env is not straight forward.
Update (about 24hrs after the error started happening). The error has stopped.

check where you images hosted have any ssl issues

All my images are loaded from local. The error seems very random. I made a simplified version of the image that loads 2 images from local & hits 1 external api. This is working but my original image is not. The only difference I can tell is that the failing image is trying to render more data, but none of this has to do with a cert.

when you run on. local which is not https it can load any images but when you are in live doman with ssl it have some rules to follow that's why you are getting on live only

To clarify, I'm talking about a live domain. I meant my images are loaded from local meaning I'm loading images that are in the codebase like const logo = await fetchAsset(new URL("./assets/logo.png", import.meta.url)); & the error doesn't happen every time so something weird is going on. fetchAsset is just a wrapper around fetch that converts the image to a base64 string.

can you add code fetchAsset you code seems wrong to me local image but still you are using fectch() why ?

export async function fetchAsset(url: URL): Promise<string> {   const buffer = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());   const base64 = Buffer.from(buffer).toString("base64");   return data:image/png;base64,${base64}; }
sorry I can't get it to format properly

I thought I saw to use fetch in the next docs, what would you use? a requires? I was basing it on how next says to load fonts.

just use const logo = "./assets/logo.png" this what the issue with this ? or assets in public DIR ?
`

Assets is adjacent to the dir im working in (not public). Also next throw this error if I try your way Error: Image source must be an absolute URL

import logo from "./assets/logo.png"   use like this then. in top and then use don't  use const

If I do that I get
{
src: '/_next/static/media/logo.7ef01f5d.png',
height: 192,
width: 268,
blurDataURL: '/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo.7ef01f5d.png&w=8&q=70',
blurWidth: 8,
blurHeight: 6
}
I tried passing this to an img tag and a next Image tag, I also tried just passing the src, all resulting in errors

this is correct what error you are facing ? show screenshot

I added more error examples to the question, thanks again!

maybe i shouldnt be using edge runtime
